# Azure AD Join Default Local Administrator

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

First of all I am pretty new to Azure AD, so just excuse if the question is vague. I was trying to understand when a Windows 10 Device is AD joined, which all users will get default 'Local Administrator Role'. Will it be :

- Global Admin, Device Administrator and User who join device (as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin))

or

- Global Admin and User who adds the device (as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal))

The two documents are talking two different things. Excuse me again if this is very straightforward to answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin)  applicable to only [Azure AD join devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join-hybrid).
2. The second [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal) is for all joined devices such as *[Hybrid Azure AD joined devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join-hybrid),  [Azure AD join devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join),  [Azure AD registered devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-register)*

No, All users will not get default 'Local Administrator Role'.Azure AD adds only security principals to the local administrators group on the device as per first article.